# What is the lightest Angular 11 configuration to develop a project?

Tags: angular, gpu, angular11

I had several GPU problems this month.
I´m working on a heavy Angular 11 project and I discover after some tests that GPU matters appeared after the Angular local server was launched.
So I ran the server with `ng serve -no-live reload` without success.
What is the lightest configuration (`ts.config.json`, `angular.json`...) to work without overload the gpu ?

This is my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"],
      "@models/*": ["app/models/*"],
      "@services/*": ["app/services/*"],
      "@providers/*": ["app/providers/*"],
      "@helpers/*": ["app/helpers/*"]
    },
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

and my **angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "mmlogistic-Front": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:module": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/foo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "200kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "foo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "foo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "foo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "foo:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "foo:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@jefiozie/ngx-aws-deploy:deploy",
          "options": {
            "region": "eu-west-3",
            "bucket": "dev.foo",
            "secretAccessKey": "XXX",
            "accessKeyId": "XXX"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "foo",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```